# mysql: foreign key does not work? exist records that should not exist

Tags: mysql

mysql8.0.16, innodb.

I have two tables, defined as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE `t1` (
  `t1_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  `t2_id` int(11) DEFAULT NULL,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t1_id`),
  KEY `FKi35qhb7o9h73w2et7geh4xwvt` (`t2_id`),
  CONSTRAINT `FKi35qhb7o9h73w2et7geh4xwvt` FOREIGN KEY (`t2_id`) REFERENCES `t2` (`t2_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;

CREATE TABLE `t2` (
  `t2_id` int(11) NOT NULL AUTO_INCREMENT,
  PRIMARY KEY (`t2_id`)
) ENGINE=InnoDB DEFAULT CHARSET=utf8mb4 COLLATE=utf8mb4_0900_ai_ci;
```

I accidentally discovered: there are some records in table t1, the value of t2_id not record in table t2。as follows:

```
mysql> select t1_id, t2_id from t1 where t2_id=11624;
+----------+-----------+
| t1_id | t2_id |
+----------+-----------+
|     6 | 11624 |

mysql> select t2_id from t2 where t2_id=11624;
Empty set (0.00 sec)
```

foreign key did not work? So I attempt to insert a new record:

```
mysql> select * from t2 where t2_id=12000;
Empty set (0.00 sec)

mysql> insert into t1(t2_id) value(12000);
ERROR 1452 (23000): Cannot add or update a child row: a foreign key constraint fails (`test`.`t1`, CONSTRAINT `FKi35qhb7o9h73w2et7geh4xwvt` FOREIGN KEY (`t2_id`) REFERENCES `t2` (`t2_id`))
```

What happened? Why is there such a record(6, 11624) in the table t1? 
I have no idea.

Please help me, thank you!

Comment: Did yo have `FOREIGN_KEY_CHECKS` deactivated once in MySQL?

Comment: Thank you very much! You solved my problem! @juergen d